# How to fix error testing Authentication user?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm learning Drf, I'm figuring out to Athuenticate user login Testapi in Drf, it showing error Not valid view function or pattern name. Can Anyone suggest what is wrong with the code?

URLS.PY

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('college.urls')),
    path('auth',include('rest_framework.urls'), name='rest_framework'),


]
```

TEST.PY

```
USER_URL = reverse('auth')
class StudentsDetailsTestCase(APITestCase):

    def test_login_user(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.client.login(username='***', 
                        password='***'))
        response = self.client.get(USER_URL)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code,status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

traceback error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "C:\Users\collegedjango\MYSITE\college\tests.py", line 35, in <module>
    USER_URL = reverse('auth')
  File "C:\Users\collegedjango\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\reverse.py", line 47, in reverse
    url = _reverse(viewname, args, kwargs, request, format, **extra)
  File "C:\Users\collegedjango\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\reverse.py", line 60, in _reverse
    url = django_reverse(viewname, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, **extra)
  File "C:\Users\collegedjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 86, in reverse
    return resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\collegedjango\venv\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 729, in _reverse_with_prefix
    raise NoReverseMatch(msg)
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'auth' not found. 'auth' is not a valid view function or pattern name.


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use it with `rest_framework` because of this line `path('auth',include('rest_framework.urls'), name='rest_framework'),`

you can update reverse by `reverse(rest_framework)` or you can change line to `path('auth',include('rest_framework.urls'), name='auth'),`

Comment: no its not working i tried wth rest_framework and  with change name = auth also tried same output error showing

Comment: ,actually , first its working page not found Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/auth
Using the URLconf defined in MYSITE.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
api
marks [name='marks']
student [name='student']
student_details [name='student_info']
teacherslist [name='teacherlist']
auth login/ [name='login']
auth logout/ [name='logout']
doc/ [name='schema-swagger-ui']
The current path, auth, didn’t match any of these.